# No prompt for re-authentication with OAUth2. Why and how to force it?

Tags: google-oauth

I would like to understand something please.
I have an application based on oAuth2 with Google Accounts.

So, teh first time I connect to this website, I am redirected to the authentication page on Google domain. So I type my email and password and I dont check "trusted computer" (or "remember me", I dont remember the exact term).

The thing is if I reboot my computer or even delete my cookie (but not my history (tested with Chrome on Android phone), I am not prompted again for the authentication and I have directly access to the application.

I would like to understand why ?
If somebody can explain it to me that should be great !

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

You can actually force re-authentication in the Google OAuth api by passing `&max_auth_age=0` to the auth URL.

Source:

> Use the PAPE extension for further control of user authentication (optional)
>   Use the max_auth_age parameter in the PAPE extension to ensure that the login session of the user at Google is recent. You may also specify max_auth_age=0 to force a password reprompt.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

It's a bit confusing because they talk about OpenID, but I'm doing this successfully with Google's provided OAuth2 libs.

Answer (score 2):

The Google OAuth 2 API really doesn't give you a way to force re-authentication.  Lots of people have asked for this capability though, and maybe we should provide it.

Comment: There is "approval_prompt=force" to force reauth for web flow. The OP doesn't say which flow he is using.

Comment: Hey pinoyyid, approval_prompt=force does *not* force re-authentication, it forces re-approval of the grant.

Comment: hi tim. fair point. Authentication and approval are different, and I was possibly conflating the two. It's not clear what UX flow the OP is looking for. There is no information on how his application is maintaining user sessions. He talks about "deleting cookies" but doesn't specify which cookies. I interpreted his question as him wanting to repeat the initial flow.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say, since it depends on what the flow was that as being executed.

Generally (with oauth) you weren't being prompted for authentication. You were being prompted for authorisation. Once you've authorised, you won't be prompted again, provided of course that the browser/google have some sort of session in existence which identifies the user.

When you say "delete my cookie", which cookie?

Yo can try going to this page https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en_GB and revoke the permission. That should then cause a repeat prompt.