# How to Authenticate user, password with Google App Engine + Java?

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-api, google-apps

I need to **authenticate user** **email and password** with Google. I am using App Engine + Java environment. Is there any provision in Google APIs ?

currently i am using

```
ContactService client = new ContactService ("yourCompany-yourAppName-v1");
client.setUserCredentials("user@example.com", "pa$$word");
```

I need to replace this Google APIs. **I need to authenticate user with Google not application.**

Please suggest me how can i do this.

Comment: you cant you need to use Open Authentication.   https://developers.google.com/identity/

Comment: You can download Google API samples for java here http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/

Comment: @lulliia which one?  I just checked 4 of them they either use Oauth2 or the public api key.

Comment: @ZigMandel  i need to authenticate user against useremail and password with Goolge. I do not need User Authentication for application.

Comment: edits no longer make it a duplicate. retracted my close vote.

Comment: I have an answer, but first answer this: is the user entering their user/password from client-side? (a webpage/app) or are you doing this server-side? I have an answer for client-side. (btw sorry for the other 2 "answers" I deleted. I accidentally posted them as answers instead of comments (the s.o. webapp needs some work)

Comment: @yogesh, have you solve your problem? Is it OK for you use  OAuth2? Note, that authentication with email and password is deprecated.

Comment: @luliia yes its good to have to use OAuth2, but i am unable to get How to do it.

Comment: @ZigMandel  yes user have to enter user/pwd from client side and i will authenticate it on server-side.

Comment: ok i answered. If you dont know the oauth part, dont ask it in this question as that would be too broad. Instead read the docs and open a new question with specifics about oauth issues. make sure to read existing answers as its a usual duplicate to ask about oauth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last comment you say that the google username and password is entered in the client and validated in the server. That is NOT possible, google has deprecated the ability of an app to capture the password and thats excellent.
The only way to do this is with oauth2, BUT addionally you need to pass a special parameter `&max_auth_age=0`.
At this point this question is basically a duplicate of this: [No prompt for re-authentication with OAUth2. Why and how to force it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379627/no-prompt-for-re-authentication-with-oauth2-why-and-how-to-force-it) 
 however I didnt mark duplicate because yours is a different situation.
Explaining oauth in detail is not part of this answer as its explained well in the official documentation and many guides. Do not use the built-in appengine userService. Instead configure appengine pages so they are all public and on top implement oauth2, for example using the existing google+ javascript signin libraries (thou not sure if those let you set the max_auth_age parameter. If not, you need to roll your own oauth2 "client side 3-legged" flow. In that flow, the client will see the google login page every time, and after the client-side flow finishes, the client will end up with an access token which is what it sends to the server to validate that the user entered the correct username and password. If you include the correct scope (userinfo.email scope) then the server can use that access token to ask google the username that generated the token, thus you have validated that the client did login to google and you know their email.
But you will NOT receive the password. Just enough info to authenticate the user.

Comment: thanks, i will implement user authentication using OAUuth2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear, I'll try to respond in two way.

1) Authenticate users on appengine with custom username and password.

To do that you need the "classic" way, I suggest you to use a framework like Spring with his module "spring-security", take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/alessandro-aglietti/spring-security-basic-auth-on-appengine).

2) Authenticate users on appengine with Google Account.

This is the best way I think, you only need to follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication) guide.

Comment: i need to do not want to authenticate users on app engine, i need to authenticate others users with there passwords.

Comment: In my answer there is the solution for both cases, have you tried the first 1) one ?

Comment: @ZigMandel i need to authenticate user against useremail and password with Goolge. I do not need User Authentication for application.

Comment: Its forbidden by google. Also very bad idea to capture the user password. Thats why oauth exists. I see now its not a dup of the one i linked but has been asked before in others.

Comment: @ZigMandel yes, thats forbidden by Google. I didn't get how can i achieve this by using Oauth ?

Comment: Look at userService or roll your own oauth2

Comment: @ZigMandel you need to follow part 2) of my answer ;) on App Engine you don't need to setup your own OAuth flow if you want to authenticate Google Account

Comment: yes @aqquadro and thats exactly what I said when I mentioned "userService". I also mentioned the possibility to roll your own because userService is very outdated and has some bad features (like having to re-approve every 30 days) that you can avoid with your own oauth (like using the google+ signin button)

Comment: Sorry @ZigMandel I wanted to quote yogesh :D